# Vmware virtual distributed switch will decrease throughput performance when we enable port mirroring session

Tags: switch-statement, vmware, distributed

Please someone explain how port mirroring works in Vmware  distributed switch.If performance will get impacted if user enabled port mirroring session.

Answer (score 0):

While it is the concern of every network admin on the performance being impacted when enabling port mirroring, from the best practice guide for SDN, it is always recommended to use a separate uplink port to send mirror traffic.